# Sustituir determinados caracteres POSTGRESQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, regex, replace

estoy intentando modificar todos los registros de una tabla que cumplan una condición determinada. El problema lo tengo al intentar cumplir la condición.

La condición es eliminar las comillas simples que vayan seguidas de un *@*.
Por ejemplo, puedo contener registros que sean así:

`Registro de prueba, donde muestro 'a' y '@cau'`

Y pretendo eliminar las comillas simples que hay en @cau, quedando algo así:
`Registro de prueba, donde muestro 'a' y @cau`

He probado con lo siguiente, pero el problema es que elimina TODAS las comillas simples que hay.

```
UPDATE MITABLA
SET MICOLUMNA =  REPLACE(MICOLUMNA, '''', '')
WHERE MICOLUMNA LIKE '%''@%'
```

He leído que pueda hacerse quizás con la expresion REGEX, pero no termino de aclararme o si hay otra manera.
Gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como bien dices, con tu código eliminas todas las comillas simples, bien necesitas usar `REGEX`, en concreto, `POSTGRESQL` permite usar `REGEX_REPLACE`.

Estuve googleando, y vi una página muy interesante que te permite probar las expresiones regulares de manera muy sencilla, [regex101](https://regex101.com) , y finalmente conseguí lo que pides.

```
UPDATE MITABLA
SET MICOLUMNA =  REGEXP_REPLACE("MICOLUMNA", '\''(@[a-zA-Z0-9_]*)''', '\1', 'g')
WHERE MICOLUMNA LIKE '%''@%'
```

Con esta expresion, permite sustituir todas las comillas simples que contengan dentro un '`@`' y vayan seguidas de cualquier caracter `alfanumérico`.

Como bien dices en tu ejemplo, pasas de tener este `String`:

```
Registro de prueba, donde muestro 'a' y '@cau'
```

a este otro:

```
Registro de prueba, donde muestro 'a' y @cau
```